# activerecord can't save on association table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have [this](https://gist.github.com/luizkowalski/1fc32b0d12cb6dc19d08) schema. It seems like a many-to-many, but it was generated by EclipseLink, with these models

```
    public class LancamentoContabil implements Serializable {
     // objects 
    }

    public class MovimentacaoContabil implements Serializable, CheckPeriodo {
     @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true)
     @OrderBy("tipo DESC")
     private List<LancamentoContabil> lancamentos = newArrayList();
   }
```

I'm mapping these classes to use in a Rails project:

```
class LancamentoContabil < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'lancamentocontabil'

  belongs_to :conta, class_name: 'PlanoConta'
  belongs_to :empresa
end

class MovimentacaoContabil < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'movimentacaocontabil'

  belongs_to :empresa

  has_and_belongs_to_many :lancamentos, foreign_key: 'movimentacaocontabil_id', 
                          class_name: 'LancamentoContabil', association_foreign_key: 'lancamentos_id',
                          join_table: 'movimentacaocontabil_lancamentocontabil'

end
```

When activerecord tries to save a `MovimentacaoContabil`, I get this error:

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "movimentacaocontabil_id" violates not-null constraint`

the full sql can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/luizkowalski/6e80a8c9b7a978548bfe)

I have no idea on what is going on here...any idea are welcome

Comment: `has_and_belongs_to_many` is a many-to-many association, not a one-to-many-association, I think you need a `has_many :lancamentos...` and add a `belongs_to :movimentacao_contabil` on `LancamentoContabil`...

Comment: No, I can't do it. I don't have a `movimentacao_contabil_id` on `LancamentoContabil` nor I can change the schema